# How does one make a loopable class in Swift?

Tags: generics, swift

In Swift I've made my own container class, that acts like an array. I just can't seem to figure out how to make it so I can loop through it.

```
class List<T> {
    var items = [T]();
    func add(allItems:T...){
        items += allItems
    }
    subscript(i:Int) -> T? {
        return items[i]
    }
}

var l = List<Int>()
l.add(1,2,3,4)
l[2]! //3
```

I thought I was supposed to adopt the SequenceType protocol and create a generator that returns something that implements a generator of some sort.

If I adopt `SequenceType` protocol I and write a generate function I get the error that my `T` does not conform to the type `_CollectionType`.

My failed attempt:

```
class List<T>:SequenceType {
    var items = [T]();
    func add(allItems:T...){
        items += allItems
    }

    func generate() -> GeneratorType<T>.Element {
        return IndexingGenerator()
    }

    subscript(i:Int) -> T? {
        return items[i]
    }
}

var l = List<Int>()
l.add(1,2,3,4)
l[2]!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`items` is an `Array<T>` which already implements `SequenceType`, so why not just pass the call to your `generate()` function on to it:

```
class List<T>: SequenceType {
    var items = [T]();
    func add(allItems:T...){
        items += allItems
    }

    func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<Array<T>> {
        return items.generate()
    }

    subscript(i:Int) -> T? {
        return items[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to specify the Generator typealias to fully implement the SequenceType protocol: `typealias Generator = GeneratorOf<String>`

Comment: @drewag I thought so too, but it seems to work just fine without it in this situation; the compiler must be able to infer it.